# What is this game with the player character flying with purple wings?

Tags: game-identification

[image: Screenshot of unidentified game]

I'm trying to find the name of the game because I think it looks really good. I think it's for iOS, but if not please mention which platforms it's on.

Comment: Hi Mark!  Where's did you find this screenshot?  It's hard to make out any identifying marks on the map and seems like this could just be a WoW/Tera image overlayed with random buttons.

Comment: Why the -3? Anyway... can't tell exactly what game it is but you may be right about the iOS (the left control suggests mobile).

Comment: i thought it was an ios game cuz of the controls on the left. i thought it was legends of discord but in legend of discord is there really flying like that cuz i saw the trailer and it's not like that. i took the screenshot from an ad when i was watching a movie but ima try the discord and see cuz the ad that i got this screen shot was amazing u can fly freely

Answer (score 14):

Appears to be a game called [Legacy of Discord: Furious wings](https://lod.gtarcade.com/).  You can see some of the gameplay in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgJBF3K7fww) at around the 1:38 mark (as well as what may be your screen shot around the 2:02 mark).  Oddly, the video itself has it labeled as "Legacy of Discod: Furies Wings"  but when typing in "Legacy of Discod" Google was suggesting the other title.

As suggested, it is available for iOS (and also android).